# Don't choose the best close reason, allow multiple close reasons

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

Currently, if multiple off-topic reasons are chosen, all are displayed as a bulleted list.

I don't see why the same shouldn't be done for the other close reasons. Sometimes posts have multiple issues, being able to close something as "too broad AND vague" (or "too broad AND opinion based") sounds useful. This will help the OP improve the question as all the issues will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for initiating this thread. Does it mean every close reason gets into the final list, or just the ones which had at least two person behind that particular reason? This question arises for me when reading this thread in combination with the following: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188688/when-is-the-list-of-the-users-who-selected-a-close-reason-shown/188706#188706

Comment: related (MSO): [Multiple close reasons no longer shown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260145/multiple-close-reasons-no-longer-shown)

Comment: 7 years passed. Need more time?

Answer (score 4):

I think multiple close reasons should be mentioned for the following reason: if I vote to close for a 'minority' reason and I want to explain why the question is closed, *I have no idea*! If I close to because it is off-topic, I have no clue why other people say it is too broad. New users are confused, *why can't people tell him this question is too broad*! Clearly, according to this user, SE is populated by people who cannot back-up their arguments and shift their position (i.e. 'moving the goalposts') when convenient!

Now, all this can be solved by explaining this to the users, but *do we have to do this*? Please, for the sake of not confusing the user, show that there have been multiple close votes **OR**

Add an additional text like this (in case of possible multiple close votes):

> Please note that this is the majority reason to close your questions. It is possible some people voted to close because of other reasons. Look at the help center to be sure your question doesn't have any problems other than the current close reason or try to ask the users who close voted to explain their reasons.

Please, it would help a lot if this message that is often directed at *new users* is less confusing. Thank you. This message should be easy to implement and would help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I actually think this is a bit confusing (and if multiple OT reasons are currently being displayed, I don't know that they should be). The purpose of the close banner is to tell the OP what's wrong with their question so they can improve it. If you tell them it's too broad, okay, they can narrow the scope. If it's too vague, they can explain themselves further. If you tell them it's too broad AND vague AND opinion based....  You're just confusing them. If closevoters can't agree as to the reason why the question should be closed, that (in my experience) means the question isn't as cut-and-dry as most are. If a question is *clearly* opinion-based, all closevoters will vote for that.

Hmm, I don't know if I'm making sense. I guess I'm just saying that the purpose of the close banner is to point the user in the right direction to fix their post, and if you tell them to fix a million things at once they're just going to get confused. Chances are if they really sit down and try and correct their post to fix errors mentioned in one close reason, they're going to have made it an acceptable question in general. No additional close banners necessary.

Comment: Yes, on the other hand, we have situations where the OP may fix the ... say ... unclear bit only to be told that it's "still opinion based". I can't speak for other sites, but on Physics when multiple reasons are chosen, the question usually does deserve them so all of them are necessary for the OP to fix it. The different close reasons are orthogonal to each other, so it's OK for a question to be UWYA and POB or TB and POB or any other combo at the same time

Comment: I completely agree with Manishearth here - for example, let's say there's an unclear question about general software. Closing it as unclear may lead to an edit and attempted reopen. Closing it as belonging on [su] may lead to it being asked, as is, over there. Either way, it's not good. I don't see why, if someone can understand one reason, they can't understand multiple reasons.