# Please tell me that a custom off-topic close vote will leave a comment on their post

Tags: feature-request, comments, close-reasons

Title says it all... When I go to Close=> Off-Topic=> Other and enter a reason below, it posts a comment to the post on which I am casting said close vote. Please give us a heads-up, or remove this functionality.

Comment: Why? All the other reasons ultimately indicate as well that you've voted for the particular one, don't they? Where is the problem?

Comment: Why should the "Other" reason leave a comment, just like this one you're reading now, unlike the other reasons, that only show if the question is successfully closed?

Comment: @Bart when you get down to it, the close box only shows the reason most people voted for.  If you voted as a dup and the other 4 said "unlear", you are going to be shown as voting for unclear on the post itself.

Comment: Not *all* the other reasons are hidden until a consensus is reached. In particular, voting to close as a duplicate leaves an automatic comment. I fail to understand why you dislike this behavior in either case; please [edit] your question to clarify your objections, or your feature request is likely to be rejected out of hand.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Is that still the case? I know that for several reasons you now get to see a breakdown.... Let's see if I can find the exact mechanics somewhere. Upd: (Ah no, that's for different choices in a duplicate vote for example.)

Comment: @Bart Now that you mention it I do recall some discussion before the GCRC (Great Close Reason Change) that it would be like you described, but I haven't seen any close boxes that show multiple reasons yet.  Maybe I've only have examined consencous closures

Comment: @Bart I think we are both right.  The high level items (off-topic, duplicate, unclear, too broad) only show the reason with the most votes as before, but the sub-reasons under off topic will show all items.  I found [Manishearth's feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185983/dont-choose-the-best-close-reason-allow-multiple-close-reasons) to change the functionality to what you thought was the behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting a some kinds of close votes has always generated a comment. For example VTC as duplicate has always generated a comment. Doing so for the custom close reasons that help explain what the person did wrong is a natural extension of being helpful to the poster.

The comment is in your name so you are free to edit it (for the first 5 minutes) or remove it and say exactly what you want to say at any time, but I see no reason to remove the time saving and possibly very helpful device of informing the OP why people think their question should be closed.

VTC's are not private and there should be no expectation as to privacy in their use. Any time five voters or any number of voters plus a mod close something, the names of all those casting votes will be shown. However all their close reasons will be averaged out and only one final one chosen, so commenting is your one shot to defend your vote and it's specific reason rather than just signing off on whatever the mob picked.